# PHP: What happens after ending output buffering

Tags: php, buffer, output, flush, output-buffering

I have some code which does the following:

```
<?php
ob_flush();
ob_start();
echo $something;
ob_end_flush();

echo $another_thing;
?>
```

I can see `$something` but not `$another_thing;`

According to the manual ob_end_flush() just turns off output buffering, so if that's the case, why can't I see `$another_thing;` just the same as if I'd written without any output buffering:

```
<?php
echo $something;
echo $another_thing;
?>
```

Although I saw no reason why this should work, I decided to try calling `flush()` and `ob_flush()` after `echo $another_thing;` but this didn't help either.

What is the correct way to do this, and why doesn't the above work?

Thanks

Comment: works for me http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/06s-kmj , maybe $another_thing is empty or unprintable?

Comment: Thanks - see my answer below turns out output buffering had nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem was elsewhere!

In the course of setting `$something;` above I was calling a series of functions in a big template and somewhere buried in there was an `exit` statement, so the problem was nothing to do with output buffering!